# How to know "children" prop component type in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to assign props dynamically in the children of a component

Ex: I want to check if the component passed in children here is of type Second, and in that case, add a "prova" prop

```js
export const First: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    const modifiedChildren = useMemo(
        () =>
            React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
          if(child.type === 'Second')
                    return React.cloneElement(child, { ...child.props, prova: "ciao" });
                }
            }),
        [children]
    );
    return <>{modifiedChildren}</>;
};
```

The "type" property on the child doesnt seem to return the name as it does in Class components (as from what I've seen in other people examples), how am I supposed to do this the correct way ?

```js
// main
export const MainPage = () => {
    return (
        <First>
            <Second></Second>
        </First>
    );
};

// second
export const Second: React.FC<{ prova?: string }> = ({ prova }) => {
    return <div>{prova}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realizeed I can just do `child.type === Second` (second being the functional component/the function itself)

```js
const Second: React.FC<{ prova?: string }> = ({ prova }) => {
    return <div>{prova}</div>;
};


React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        if (child.type === Second) {
            return React.cloneElement(child, { ...child.props, prova: "bruh" });
        }
    }
}),
```